# How to pass value to variable and return it without calling recursive loop function?

Tags: php

```
function test_loop($x_values,$x, $y)
{
    $x = $x + 1;
    if($x < 4)
    {
        //I want to add $x value into $x_values variable, eg : $x_values = $x_values . $x;
        //but $x_values = $x_values . $x; is not working, so I force to use $x_values = test_loop($x_values . $x . "##", $x, $y);
        $x_values = test_loop($x_values . $x . "##", $x, $y);
    }

    //loop again if y is not = 3;
    $y = $y + 1;
    if($y < 3)
    {
        echo "kkk" . $y . "<br/>";
        $x_values = test_loop($x_values . $x . "##", $x, $y); 
    }else{
        echo "---------------------<br/>";
    }

    return $x_values; 
}

function abc(){
    $bababa = test_loop(0,1,0);

    echo $bababa;
}

abc();
```

Output :

```
kkk1
kkk2
---------------------
kkk1
kkk2
---------------------
kkk1
kkk2
---------------------
kkk2
---------------------
02##3##4##5##3##4##2##3##4##3##
```

How to make the output become :

```
kkk1
kkk2
---------------------
02##3##
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try to make `$x_values` an array, and add values in `$x_values` as array items, `$x_values[] = $x;` and then when you're ready, just [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) those values into a string. Like this:

```
function test_loop($x_values,$x, $y)
{
    $x = $x + 1;
    if($x < 4)
    {
        $x_values[] = $x;
    }

//loop again if y is not = 3;
$y = $y + 1;
if($y < 3)
{
    echo "kkk" . $y . "<br/>";
    $x_values[] = $x;
}else{
    echo "---------------------<br/>";
}

return implode($x_values); 
}
```

Just make sure that you also pass `$x_values` as an array initially:

```
function abc(){
    $bababa = test_loop([0],1,0);

    echo $bababa;
}
```

Comment: increase if($x < 10) and if($y < 5), may I know why it loop 1 time only? why it fail to loop 4 times?

Comment: As far as I can see, there are no loops in this function. The way it used to be in your code, it would loop recursively, because you called the function again inside. However, when we got rid of those call, there are no more loops in here. If you want to loop it, or it seems to loop until certain condition is met, you should try `while(condition) {...}`. For example, `while($x < 10) { //do something }`